# Vuejs 2 using filterBy and orderBy in the same computed property

Tags: sorting, vuejs2

I am having a hard time trying to joing a filterBy with orderBy, on **vuejs 2.0**, with all research I have found about this subject, as of link on the bottom of my question.

This is my filter, which is working:

```
// computed() {...
filteredResults() {
    var self = this
    return self.results
        .filter(result => result.name.indexOf(self.filterName) !== -1)
}
```

A method called in the component:

```
// methods() {...
customFilter(ev, property, value) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    this.filterBook = value
}
```

In the component:

```
// Inside my component
<a href="#" @click="customFilter($event, 'name', 'Name..')">Name..</a>
```

And another filter, which works as well:

```
// computed() {...
orderByResults: function() {
    return _.orderBy(this.results, this.sortProperty, this.sortDirection)
}
```

To comply with my orderBy I have this method:

```
// methods() {...
sort(ev, property) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    if (this.sortDirection == 'asc' && this.sortProperty == property ) {
        this.sortDirection = 'desc'
    } else {
        this.sortDirection = 'asc'
    }
    this.sortProperty = property
}
```

And to call it I have the following:

```
// Inside my component
<a href="#" @click="sort($event, 'name')">Name..</a>
```

I have found in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter) how we use this OrderBy, and in [this very long conversation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2756) how to use *filter* joint with *sort*, but I could really not implement it...

Which should be some like this:

```
filteredThings () {
    return this.things
      .filter(item => item.title.indexOf('foo') > -1)
      .sort((a, b) => a.bar > b.bar ? 1 : -1)
      .slice(0, 5)
  }
```

I could not make this work...

I tried in many forms as of:

```
.sort((self.sortProperty, self.sortDirection) => this.sortDirection == 'asc' && this.sortProperty == property ? this.sortDirection = 'desc' : this.sortDirection = 'asc' )
```

But still, or it does not compile or it comes with errors, such as:

*property not defined* (which is defines such as I am using it in the other method)
*method of funcion not found* (is happens when comment my method *sort*.. maybe here is what I am missing something)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ideas of your approach seem valid, but without a full example it's hard to tell what might actually be wrong.

Here's a simple example of sorting and filtering combined. The code can easily be extended e.g. to work with arbitrary fields in the test data. The filtering and sorting is done in the same computed property, based on the parameters set from the outside. Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqawared/).

```
<div id="app">
    <div>{{filteredAndSortedData}}</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="filterValue" placeholder="Filter">
        <button @click="invertSort()">Sort asc/desc</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                testData: [{name:'foo'}, {name:'bar'}, {name:'foobar'}, {name:'test'}],
                filterValue: '',
                sortAsc: true
            };
        },
        computed: {
            filteredAndSortedData() {
                // Apply filter first
                let result = this.testData;
                if (this.filterValue) {
                    result = result.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.filterValue));
                }
                // Sort the remaining values
                let ascDesc = this.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
                return result.sort((a, b) => ascDesc * a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
            }
        },
        methods: {
            invertSort() {
                this.sortAsc = !this.sortAsc;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nicely done! Thank you very much for your time. Only thing it's missing is the option to send the field name, as of **property** in my example. What I have is a book, so, the user must want to order by *book name*, *author*, *editor* etc. This is where in my example I had the **_.orderBy(Array, Field, Direction)**. Cheers!

Comment: I might solved it by having an external function **by()** which will grab the field name. I will try to do so, and return to post in the comments here.

Comment: @Aletheios Would you mind editing to show how you would extend this to work with arbitrary fields in the test data? Can't get my head around how to assign and use a variable for the "name" property in the sort function's localeCompare method.

Comment: figured it out! Just need to pass a property as a callback and then use it like this: `a[property].localCompare(b[property])`